# Teradata SQL Assistant/Studio on Multiple Monitors

Tags: teradata

Please, is there a way how to work with Teradata SQL Assistant on two monitors?

In an ideal way to have Query Window on one monitor and Answerset Window on the second one? Running a Query on one results in an Answerset on the second one.

I am used to SQL Assistant but did not find a way how to exploit two monitors.

Thanks, Robert

Comment: No, SQLA is an MDI application. You can't move the child windows outside the parent frame.

Comment: Thanks, that is unfortunate. And what about SQL Studio/Studio Express?

Comment: Studio is Java/Eclipse based but similar considerations apply - you can't move panels outside the parent window to have editor on one screen and answerset on another.